# Python - Mongoengine: date range query

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongoengine

I am relatively new to mongoDb in python, so kindly help
I have created a collection called waste:

```
class Waste(Document):
    meta = {'collection': 'Waste'}
    item_id = IntField(required=True)
    date_time_record = DateTimeField(default=datetime.utcnow)
    waste_id = IntField(unique=True, required=True)
    weight = FloatField(required= True)
```

I want to do a range query for a given start and end date:
I have tried the following query:

```
start = datetime(start_year, start_month, start_day)
end = datetime(end_year, end_month, end_day)
kwargs['date_time_record'] = {'$lte': end, '$gte': start}
reports = Waste.objects(**kwargs).get()
```

But I keep getting the error: DoesNotExist: Waste matching query does not exist.

the date value being sent as:

```
{
    "start_year": 2020,
    "start_month" : 5,
    "start_day" : 10,
    "end_year": 2020,
    "end_month" : 5,
    "end_day" : 20
}
```

when I try to get the first object from the collection, the output in json is:

```
{"_id": {"$oid": "5ebbcf126fdbb9db9f74d24a"}, "item_id": 96387295, "date_time_record": {"$date": 1589366546870}, "waste_id": 24764942, "weight": 32546.0}
```

a $date is added and I am unable to decipher the numbers in the date field. But when I look at the data using the mongo compass it looks just fine:
[image: snapshot of the document to be found]

There exist a record in the given date range so I am unable to understand where am I going wrong.

Comment: PyMongo does not define anything called "IntField".

Comment: Those numbers are called _timestamp_ (multiplied by 1000 i think). I would be tempted to compare dates using timestamps meanwhile someone gives you a proper answer.

Comment: @D.SM yes I tagged it wrongly as pymongo, it was mongoEngine

Answer (score 1):

I got this working by using Q:
the query I used is

```
reports = Waste.objects((Q(date_time_record__gte=start) & Q(date_time_record__lte=end)))
```

The response is:

```
[{"_id": {"$oid": "5ebbcf126fdbb9db9f74d24a"}, "item_id": 96387295, "date_time_record": {"$date": 1589366546870}, "waste_id": 24764942, "weight": 32546.0}]
```